# Multiple https entrypoints in kubernetes

Tags: traefik

I'm planning to use traefik as my ingress-controller in kubernetes. I saw that when running alone you can define by yourself the entry points. I would like to know if I can do the same in kubernetes. Basically I would like to define a sort of configuration like this in kubernetes and who it would be.

```
[entryPoints]
   [entryPoints.http]
   address = ":80"
     [entryPoints.http.redirect]
       entryPoint = "https"
   [entryPoints.https]
   address = ":443"
     [entryPoints.https.tls]
       [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
       CertFile = "integration/fixtures/https/first.com.cert"
       KeyFile = "integration/fixtures/https/first.com.key"
   [entryPoints.https]
   address = ":444"
     [entryPoints.https.tls]
       [[entryPoints.https.tls.certificates]]
       CertFile = "integration/fixtures/https/second.com.cert"
       KeyFile = "integration/fixtures/https/second.com.key"
```

And then associate different backends to my different entry points.

Answer (score -1):

Every Traefik configuration consists of [two parts](http://docs.traefik.io/basics/#configuration): A static and a dynamic one. The former can be provided through multiple means, such as command-line arguments or a configuration file. The latter is updated dynamically, with the concrete implementation being dependent to the specific provider involved.

Since the entry points are part of the static configuration, all you need to do is pass them in a format suitable to your needs. For instance, if you wanted to use a configuration file, just store the TOML configuration you have given in your question into a file and pass it to Traefik via the `--configfile` switch. (On Kubernetes, chances are you want to do that through a *ConfigMap* object.)

The complete documentation for the TOML file is given [here](http://docs.traefik.io/toml/). Supposedly, you'd be mostly interested in the parts that may apply to all providers (i.e., everything above the *Configuration backends* heading) and the *Kubernetes backend* section.

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question clearly - the question was referring to specifying multiple entry points - instead you have given him an overview of how Traefik works, which is just copying almost verbatim from the docs. Why not provide a specific example?